# Is there a way get count an Instagram Hashtag Count?

Tags: instagram

Looking for a simple way either as web service/site with an API, or directly via the Instagram API to count the number of occurances of a Hashtag. I know of 2 websites that provided Instagram search results but they do not have APIs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like the [/tags/tag-name](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/#get_tags) endpoint will give you what you want:

> Get information about a tag object.

Here's their example:

Query: https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/nofilter?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN

Response:

```
{
    "data": {
        "media_count": 472,
        "name": "nofilter",
    }
}
```

[edit]
Just tested it with a fairly generic tag ("cowboys"), and this was the response:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "code": 200
    },
    "data": {
        "media_count": 1195735,
        "name": "cowboys"
    }
}
```

~1.2 million looks like a fairly reasonable number to me.

Comment: Thanks super helpful. Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: Link is at the top of the question: http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/#

Comment: Please note that the access token you provided in the original version of this answer is now compromised and can be accessed via the edit history. If this was one of your actual access tokens, you’ll probably want to invalidate it and generate a new one.

Comment: Just wondering if this was deprecated. It seems that with the new Graph API there's no way of getting the media count for a hashtag. Is that correct?

Comment: @Alejandro Corredor Did you find an answear to that question? Or a solution to get hashtags media count?

Comment: @Abv yeah, you can use the unofficial API found at https://github.com/dilame/instagram-private-api. I don't exactly remember right now, but after inspecting that repo and the endpoints it listed, I went to the browser and was able to query specific tags from the public API, which did bring the media count (this is not the same as the Graph API).

Comment: @Alejandro Corredor thanks for your reply. Do you know if it’s allowed to use this unofficial Api?  My app is already using official instagram graph api and is on ios

Comment: @Geoff: The old API is now deprecated; it has been replaced with the Graph API. What solution do you recommend now?

Answer (score 2):

**As of August 9, 2022, Geoff's answer now no longer works.**

Instead, submit a "GET" request to "https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/(insert hashtag name here)/?__a=1"

The response will be a JSON object that looks like this:

```
{"graphql":{"hashtag":{"id":xxxx,"name":name,"edge_hashtag_to_media":{"count":123456789}}}}
```

The "count" property of "edge_hashtag_to_media" will give you the number of posts with that hashtag.